# Is it possible to resolve a bpy path as pure string?

Tags: python, scripting

Is it possible in python to convert a bpy path into a pure string?

```
def resolve_as_string(path) -> str:
    return str_convert(path)

mystring = resolve_as_string(bpy.data.objects)

print(mystring) # outputs pure string 'bpy.data.objects'
```

Comment: `return repr(path)`?

Comment: @XY have you tried it? it doesn't work. for example `repr(bpy.context.object)` returns `bpy.data.objects['Cube']` instead of the exact string `"bpy.context.object"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Blender python, it's not possible to convert a `bpy.path` object into a string directly the way you described it because bpy paths are not objects themselves but are represented by classes, and these classes don't have any method or attribute that could return a string representation of the path.

The only way to get the string representation of a bpy path is to hardcode it as a string as I explained earlier in the example `"bpy.data.objects"` in this case.

```
def resolve_as_string():
    return "bpy.data.objects"
```

In this example, the function `resolve_as_string` will always return the string `"bpy.data.objects"` which is the string representation of the bpy path that you passed as a parameter.